# Determine When a File Was Merged From Another Branch (Mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We are currently using Mercurial to manage our code and have set it up with two main branches; default and stable.

We were hoping to be able to find when a particular file was added to the stable branch, but have been unable to work out how this is possible.

As an example, we have a file that is in the stable branch (merged from default), but when trying to determine at what stage the file was merged into the stable branch, we can only see when the file was added to the repository (default branch).

i.e.

```
hg log <filename> --verbose
```

... only shows a single changeset.

It is possible to work out when it was added by going through a tedious process of iterating through each of the necessary revisions and identify at which one the file appears, but hopefully there is a more elegant approach!

EDIT: The following steps can be used to demonstrate the issue:

```
hg init

echo "syntax: glob" > .hgignore
hg addremove
hg commit -u testuser -m "new repository"


hg branch stable
hg commit -u testuser -m "new branch"
hg update default

echo "The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog." > test.txt 
hg addremove
hg commit -u testuser -m "new file"

hg update stable
hg merge default
hg commit -u testuser -m 'mock release'
hg update default
hg merge stable
hg commit -u testuser -m "switch to development branch (default)"
```

The test.txt file is now part of the stable repository....

```
hg update stable --clean
hg log .\test.txt

changeset:   3:ca4338ed2c56
user:        testuser
date:        Mon Aug 03 15:52:48 2015 +0100
summary:     new file
```

… however with the –b stable option no results are shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can use revsets in `hg log` (long way, nicer results) or choose shorter (and slightly dirty) way with log options ans eyes:

`hg log FILENAME -b stable` will produce list of changesets, earliest (by rev-id) will be moment of appearing FILENAME in branch

**Edit:**
Tested your sample repo with such history

hg log -v

```
changeset:   4:b9ab93cb4a0a
tag:         tip
parent:      2:4733dc2d6b62
parent:      3:bdd73f64f96f
user:        *
date:        Wed Aug 05 00:37:55 2015 +0500
description:
Back to devel


changeset:   3:bdd73f64f96f
branch:      stable
parent:      1:7c6de35e9ca2
parent:      2:4733dc2d6b62
user:        *
date:        Wed Aug 05 00:36:54 2015 +0500
description:
Mock release

changeset:   2:4733dc2d6b62
parent:      0:81adee946a99
user:        *
date:        Wed Aug 05 00:35:13 2015 +0500
files:       test.txt
description:
File added

changeset:   1:7c6de35e9ca2
branch:      stable
user:        *
date:        Wed Aug 05 00:33:26 2015 +0500
description:
Stable branch created

changeset:   0:81adee946a99
user:        *
date:        Wed Aug 05 00:32:22 2015 +0500
files:       .hgignore
description:
New repo
```

(note missing "files" in some changesets, especially - mergesets: *untouched* files *doesn't appear* in list), but

```
hg  log -r "contains('test.txt')" -T "{rev}:{node|short} - {branch}\n"
2:4733dc2d6b62 - default
3:bdd73f64f96f - stable
4:b9ab93cb4a0a - default
```

because `hg help revsets`

> "contains(pattern)"
>   The revision's manifest contains a file matching
>   pattern (but might not   modify it).

and final (additionally polished) revset for log: `contains('test.txt') and branch (stable) and merge()`

```
hg  log -r "contains('test.txt') and branch (stable) and merge()" -T "{rev}:{node|short}\n"
3:bdd73f64f96f
```

For numerous merge-operations you may want to have revset enclosed in a predicate first() in order to get first appearing file. And such revset (parametrized) is good candidate for adding it `[revsetalias]` and, maybe, log with revsetalias - to `[alias]`

**Sample2**

Just used on real [HGSubversion repository](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion) with random file

```
hg  log -r "contains('tests/test_pull.py') and branch (stable) and merge()" -T "{rev}:{node|short}\n"
1106:5cb6c95e0283
1255:139a44a63090
1303:553c40023729
1323:6fd0ec01553b
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The -b stable option comes back with no results, even though I can see that the referenced file exists in the stable repository. I'll post an example on how to reproduce what I'm seeing, which may better explain the issue (or highlight what I am doing wrong!).

Comment: @JinxedNZ - solution (draft) added